# SQL query to get date as 5th of month year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds dates like this in SQL server. Could you please let me know how can U achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Create a variable with value as 5 and use date function in SQL to get the Month and Year.

Comment: sorry removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
select '5th of '+DATENAME(month, '01/01/2020')+ ' '+ DATENAME(year, '01/01/2020')
```

OR

```
select '5th of '+DATENAME(month, '01/01/2020')+ ' '+ RIGHT('01/01/2020',4)
```

[DATENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns a character string representing the specified datepart of the specified date

Output

```
5th of January 2020
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I sorted it by declaring as  declare
@5th varchar(5)
set @5th='5th' and then converted month and year from the date and did a concatenation   like '5th' as duedate,@5th+' '+DATENAME(mm,oi.date_due)+' '+datename(yy,oi.date_due) as date

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

`select FORMAT(date , 'dd o\f MMMM yy') from table`

Comment: Hello Matteo , welcome to SO ,  a short answer like this can be a comment

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FORMAT()` function as

```
SELECT FORMAT([Date], '5\t\h o\f MMMM yyyy') Result
FROM YourTable;
```